# Gmail video chat-unable to add contact

Tags: iphone

i just bought my first iPad and am trying to set up video chat . I downloaded chrome as my browser and downloaded the plugin hangout. But when I try to log in, I get the msg 'unable to add contact'. I have no idea what to do next. help!!!

Comment: once in hangouts you need to see: https://plus.google.com/hangouts/_/.......

Comment: Where do I find Admin Console??

Comment: Are you already in Google +

Comment: I went to admin.google.com and click on sign in with my google account login credentials And the screen just changes to choose an account. I don't get anywhere. I even just created a new Google account and the same thing happens. I don't understand what I am doing wrong. I am not an administrator just a frustrated user

Comment: Yes, I am in google+ but I have no idea what to do there.

Comment: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/apps/08Hvu1wWWrA